# Spring-batch : How to catch exception message with skip method in spring batch?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

I am a novice of spring batch.
My question is how to catch exceptions with the skip method in spring-batch?
As I know, we can use a skip method to skip them when some exceptions happened in spring batch.
But how can I get the exception message with skip method?
somebody suggested me use **SkipListener** ,this class has three call back method like **onSkipInProcess()**,but it is no use for me.
And ItemProcessListener did not work either.

The code like below:(I use skip method to ignore the exception and two listeners to receive the exception info)

```
Step mainStep = stepBuilder.get("run")
        .<ItemProcessing, ItemProcessing>chunk(5)
        .faultTolerant()
        .skip(IOException.class).skip(SocketTimeoutException.class)//skip IOException here
        .skipLimit(2000)
        .reader(reader)
        .processor(processor)
        .writer(writer)
        .listener(stepExecListener)
        .listener(new ItemProcessorListener()) //add process listener
        .listener(new SkipExceptionListener()) //add skip exception listner
        .build();
```

ItemProcessorListener like below:

```
//(this class implements ItemProcessListener )
{
    @Override
    public void beforeProcess(Object item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void afterProcess(Object item, Object result) {
        logger.info("invoke remote finished, item={},result={}",item,result);

    }
    @Override
    public void onProcessError(Object item, Exception e) {
        logger.error("invoke remote error, item={},exception={},{}",item,e.getMessage(),e);
    }
}
```

SkipExceptionListener like below:

```
//(implements SkipListener<Object, Object>)
{

    @Override
    public void onSkipInRead(Throwable t) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }

    @Override
    public void onSkipInWrite(Object item, Throwable t) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }

    @Override
    public void onSkipInProcess(Object item, Throwable t) {
        logger.info("invoke remote finished,item={},itemJsonStr={},errMsg={},e={}",
                    item,
                    JSONObject.toJSONString(item),
                    t.getMessage(),
                    t);
    }
}
```

The issue is that all logger did not work. Actually the skip method does work well, I can get the skip count in table batch_step_execution. I am not sure these two listeners whether be callback. Who can tell me how can I do? Or is there anything else? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

> How to catch exception message with skip method in spring batch?

You can do that by implementing the `SkipListener` interface or extending the `SkipListenerSupport` class. All methods in the `SkipListener` interface have a `Throwable` parameter which is the exception thrown and that caused the item to be skipped. This is where you can get the exception message. Here is an example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.SkipListener;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.ListItemReader;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyJob {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<Integer> itemReader() {
        return new ListItemReader<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10));
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Integer> itemWriter() {
        return items -> {
            for (Integer item : items) {
                System.out.println("item = " + item);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<Integer, Integer> itemProcessor() {
        return item -> {
            if (item.equals(7)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Sevens are not accepted!!");
            }
            return item;
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step() {
        return steps.get("step")
                .<Integer, Integer>chunk(5)
                .reader(itemReader())
                .processor(itemProcessor())
                .writer(itemWriter())
                .faultTolerant()
                .skip(IllegalArgumentException.class)
                .skipLimit(3)
                .listener(new MySkipListener())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobs.get("job")
                .start(step())
                .build();
    }

    public static class MySkipListener implements SkipListener<Integer, Integer> {

        @Override
        public void onSkipInRead(Throwable t) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSkipInWrite(Integer item, Throwable t) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSkipInProcess(Integer item, Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("Item " + item + " was skipped due to: " + t.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyJob.class);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
        Job job = context.getBean(Job.class);
        jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
    }

}
```

In this example, `MySkipListener` implements `SkipListener` and gets the message from the exception as you are trying to do. The example reads numbers from 1 to 10 and skips number 7. You can run the `main` method and should see the following output:

```
item = 1
item = 2
item = 3
item = 4
item = 5
item = 6
item = 8
item = 9
item = 10
Item 7 was skipped due to: Sevens are not accepted!!
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Does it have to be inside the MyJob class or is this just for convenience of the example?

Comment: No it doesn't have to be inside the `MyJob` class. I added it there for convenience. The example is self-contained, you can run the main method and see how things work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It seens my previous code is not different from you. Don't known why my side don't work. I will try it again tomorrow in company.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I thought it should be work fine with implementation when i move the Skip-Listener  inside the job class. And define the class as static like you. I thought static class would be initialize at first. So it will work fine. But in fact  it's not work either. I think the difference is your spring-batch version is not same as me? My version is 3.0.

Comment: I use version 4.0.1 but it should work fine with version 3.0. The listener class can be non static, it does not matter. Here is a project you can play with: https://github.com/benas/sandbox/tree/master/so51981640 . It uses version 3 with the listener class being non static and defined outside the MyJob class.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get it to work either with implementing SkipListener (would be nice to know why) but in the end I went with the annotation way which is only briefly mentioned in the docs. Also somebody had a similar issue here using the implementation method ([question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638924/spring-batch-skiplistener-not-called-when-exception-occurs-in-reader)) and the guy in the answer uses this annotation method instead of implementing the interface.

Example bean:

```
@Component
public class CustomSkippedListener {

    @OnSkipInRead
    public void onSkipInRead(Throwable throwable) {
    }

    @OnSkipInWrite
    public void onSkipInWrite(FooWritingDTO fooWritingDTO, Throwable throwable) {
        LOGGER.info("balabla" + throwable.getMessage());
    }

    @OnSkipInProcess
    public void onSkipInProcess(FooLoaderDTO fooLoaderDTO, Throwable throwable) {
        LOGGER.info("blabla"  + throwable.getMessage());
    }

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomSkippedListener.class);


}
```

then autowire and include in the step chain as you did.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: It can be work with annotation (@OnSkipInProcess) . I also would be known why implements the interface can't work.  Is it a bug?

Comment: The skip listener can be an annotation-based component or implement the SkipListener interface. Both should work fine. I added an example to my answer showing a listener that implements the interface and which is invoked as expected.