Spring Batch SkipListener onSkipInWrite does not return only one item with Oracle
Good morning
I have a Spring Batch Job with one Step and a SkipListener implemented.
The problem is when the ItemWriter inserts records by chunk in an Oracle database with an error on one insert (an integrity constraint error by example). The OnWriteInSkip method in the  SkipListener is then called several times with several insert errors instead of only once with the insert in error. In the table in the Oracle database, it is fine, only one record is skipped, the one containing the error.
Example :
First use case :
ItemWriter inserts primary keys 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9 in a table in Oracle database (7 primary key inserted twice)
=> OnWriteInSkip in SkipListener is called for 7, 2, 3, 4, 9 and only primary key 7 is skipped in database
Second use case :
ItemWriter inserts primary keys 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 in a table in Oracle database
=> OnWriteInSkip in SkipListener is not called and no record skipped in database as espected
Environement : Spring Boot 3.3.6, Spring Batch 5.1.2, Oracle 21
Job
return new StepBuilder("customStep", jobRepository)
            .<CustomItem, CustomItem> chunk(400, transactionManager)
            .reader(reader)
            .processor(processor)
            .writer(writer)
            .faultTolerant()
            .skip(Exception.class)
            .skipLimit(1000)
            .listener(skipListener)
            .build();

SkipListener is a classical one with a logger in the OnWriteInSkip method
I would be happy to have an understanding and a solution to this problem. I have tried several fixes without success. Has anyone faced this problem or has a solution to resolve it ? Thank you

Seems to be a known problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61756484/springbatch-chunkstep-retried-on-exception-in-writer-even-with-neverretrypolicy/61770872#61770872

Can you share more about your application?
If I put the following in an empty Spring Boot application with H2 on the classpath, then everything works as expected:
@Configuration
public class BatchConfiguration {

  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BatchConfiguration.class);

  @Bean
  Job job(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager, JobRepository jobRepository) {
    return new JobBuilder("job", jobRepository)
        .start(new StepBuilder("step", jobRepository)
            .<Integer, Integer>chunk(400, transactionManager)
            .reader(reader())
            .writer(writer(null))
            .faultTolerant()
            .skip(Exception.class)
            .skipLimit(1000)
            .listener(new BatchSkipListener())
            .build())
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  @StepScope
  ListItemReader<Integer> reader() {
    return new ListItemReader<>(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9));
  }

  @Bean
  ItemWriter<Integer> writer(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    return chunk -> jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(
        "INSERT INTO target_table VALUES (?)",
        chunk.getItems().stream().map(i -> new Object[] {i}).toList(),
        new int[] {Types.BIGINT}
    );
  }

  static class BatchSkipListener implements SkipListener<Integer, Integer> {

    @Override
    public void onSkipInWrite(Integer item, Throwable t) {
      LOG.warn("At {} with {}", item, t.getClass());
    }

  }

}

The content of the schema.sql is:
CREATE TABLE target_table (ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY);

